# How can i secure a web application?

Tags: spring, security, jsp, spring-security

I have a web application (JSP) and i need to limit the access, so only the logged in users see the application. I looked it and i found many diferrent approaches. Some say to use cookies, sessions or frameworks such as Spring Security. 
 What should i use? So far i have a medium experience in java and jsp programming, so what do you recommend me to to do?
thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of preparing home made version of Spring Security I propose to use it directly. Consider following advantages:

- In the future if you need some new security features then you can just turn them on instead of developing them from zero (for example LDAP authentication, SSO, ...)
- There are chances that new developer is already familiar with your security framework (on the other side it is sure that it will be not familiar with your home made labrary)
- Most of them have good documentation so learning cuve is small when we talk about basic URL  authorization (do you have enough time to prepare the same level of documentation for your home made library?).
- They have built-in support against attacks like session fixation, etc.
- They have multiple extension points, so you will be not limited by framework (you will be able to add / modify necessary functionality).
- They have moduled structure, you do not need to load all modules / know about them. Use only what you need.

It may be useful for you to check [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) and [Spring Security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security).

In a case of Spring Security if you start reading official documentation from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started) then you can prepare all conf for basic URL authorization (with hard coded users in the conf) in less than 30 minutes. Then you need to include corresponding jars in your classpath (for Spring and Spring Security) and that's all. Turn on debug logging for `org.springframework.security` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the use of a servlet filter. Store the logged-in user in the session and configure a filter to check the user is logged when he/she attempts to access the secure directories of your site (via url-pattern).

Basic info here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_writing_filters.htm.

But here's something more specific to get you started.

Create a class that implements javax.servlet.Filter, override the doFilter method and check that the user is logged in and configure the urlPatterns using annotations.

The annotation on the filter would be something like this:

```
@WebFilter(filterName="LoggingFilter", urlPatterns={"/secured/*"})
```

the directory that you wish to protect is called 'secured'.

In the class override the doFilter() method and check that the user is logged in:

```
User user = session.getAttribute("user");
if (user != null) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // User is logged in so forward response.
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("login"); // User not logged in so redirect to login page.
}
```

This is an effective way to restrict a logged in user to specified parts of the site. This simple example can be extended to restrict access to different parts of the site based on user type or some other criteria.

Comment: Thank you, very useful informations.So, you suggest not using a framework, like Spring Security to do that @Alex Theedom

Comment: Spring Security is the same thing under the bonnett. It intercepts HTTP requests via a servlet filter. The same as above but Spring Security has much more configuration and therefore more complications. The choice you make depends on a whole range of interconnecting factors. The option above is simple and easy to implement whie Spring Security is more complicated and perhaps more than you need for your project. Although if you are already using Spring it makes sense to use Spring Security.